# Idiomatic use of fmap with function composition

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell, but I'm loving learning about it, it's so different from everything I've used before. I've read a book or two on Monads and how they affect flow, but I'm still having a bit of trouble getting the hang of it. To get better I'm working through the excellent Advent of Code problems, right now I'm on [problem 2](http://adventofcode.com/day/2), I've posted my code below and it works properly, but doesn't feel as clean as it could be.

Specifically I'm wondering how I can clean up this:

`main = getContents >>= (return . sum . (fmap getSquareFootage) . lines) >>= print`

I don't like mixing function composition AND fmap AND `>>=` in a line like that, I find it hard to read. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve the same result? I'm also open to any and all Haskell style advice, I don't really have anyone to talk to about this, Thanks!

TLDR; How can I idiomatically combine fmap, `.` and `>>=`?

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= (return . sum . (fmap getSquareFootage) . lines) >>= print

getSquareFootage :: String -> Int
getSquareFootage box = area dims + slack dims
    where dims =  read <$> splitOn "x" box
        slack = minimum . sides
        sides [l, w, h] = [l*w, w*h, h*l]
        area [l, w, h] = 2*l*w + 2*w*h + 2*h*l
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `return` at the end of a Kleisli arrow only to feed the result to another one, you could just precompose it as a pure function: `return . f >>= q` is equivalent to `q . f` by the monad laws.

```
main = getContents >>= print . sum . (fmap getSquareFootage) . lines
```

I've used that the fixity of `.` is higher than `infixl 1 >>=`. Speaking of fixity: you never need to surround function calls with parens, if they're already surrounded by infixes! And since your specialised to lists, you can use `map` instead of `fmap` (though this is a matter of taste).

```
main = getContents >>= print . sum . map getSquareFootage . lines
```

Not too bad IMO, though it could be argued that the order is confusing. You can make it all right-to-left,

```
main = print . sum . map getSquareFootage . lines =<< getContents
```

or left-to-right if you prefer

```
import Control.Arrow

main = getContents >>= (lines >>> map getSquareFootage >>> sum >>> print)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I like this one personally:

    main = print . sum . map getSquareFootage . lines =<< getContents

My misconception was that `print` had the type `IO a -> IO ()` instead of `a -> IO ()` Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

well I would put this into a do block:

```
main = do
    ls <- lines <$> getContents
    let s = sum $ map getSquareFootage ls
    print s
```